# Screensaver installation

Tags: release-loki, settings, applications, themes

I have accidentally installed the `mate-screensaver` using the AppCenter. Which did mess up many visual elements (icons, window decorations, and such). I will probably end up reinstalling the OS as I did not find an easy way to fix it (it is a new install, not a huge deal). However, is there a recommended screensaver package which is known to work well with Elementary OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a screensaver package that works well with elementary OS.

Other popular screensaver options include XScreensaver and GNOME Screensaver, but I wasn't able to find much information about whether these work well with elementary. There are [some reports](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/2jprqp/lock_screen_problems_freya/) of GNOME Screensaver messing up the lock screen shortcut.

Here's Danielle Foré, the founder of elementary, on screensavers (see [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/755502)):

> I think the general consensus, last time it was discussed, was that it was better to just turn the display off.
>
> As stated before, the periodic table has nothing to do with our brand.
>
> I'm leaning towards this being a wont fix. Screeensavers are kind of an outdated concept, IMO.

Comment: Ryan, Thank you for the pointers. I understand the reasoning (although do not agree with it :) ) and it makes sense. At the relatively early project stage a screensaver is probably not the top priority. For the record, I use screensaver not to save from a screen burnout (which seems to be an issue of a past, though IDK), but as a mild stimulating distraction with a photo album when I am stuck and thinking. Cheers.

Comment: would definitely be nice to have.  I have my PC go to suspend after 3 hours, but I'd love for it to look pretty when not in use but still on.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem with screen saver. After 15 minutes is turning my screen black and is logging out. 
 I try turn of in gnome system settings from user privileges, but it did't worked.
 I try install external program "light-locker-screen" but i have problem with modules from  python.

Then I come up with idea that I will run command from terminal as super user, and run gnome-control-center.

```
sudo su
#<password>
gnome-control-center
```

and then go to power settings, where "turn of screen when not active" was set to 15 minutes, so I changed to never, and also I went to security & privacy settings and switch Locking off for both "lock on sleep" and "lock after screen turns off"

I think that you need super-user privileges to effectively change these settings. Maybe solution is that you can only make this changes as a super user?

Comment: Omg thank you bro! I search this option 2 hours! Its so stupid devs they can just copy this settings to "Power" from Security and Privacy