# Installation of xscreensaver messing up interface

Tags: suspend, user-interface

I installed xscreensaver after having an issue that my laptop suddenly didn't enter sleep mode automatically anymore, and after an initial period where all remained fine, I noticed my login window being changed, the photo appearing square and the login form roughened, then after rebooting, I noticed many interface changes; I installed the app using the AppCenter. Which thus did mess up many visual elements (icons, window decorations, and such). How can I restore the interface to normal?

A similar issue has been reported [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11265/screensaver-installation), with another screensaver app, mate.

Answer (score 0):

The answer apparently lies in the interface tweaks. I have it installed on my system.

Open system settings > tweaks

- GTK+ > Elementary
- Icons > Elementary

Restores the interface to the original settings. Though, I don't know the reason the settings were changed by xscreensaver, nor if the fix is permanent, but it does the job.